# Add Sound to Flash-Like Button With jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have made a flashLike button with jquery via this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation li a').append('<span class="hover"></span>').each(function () {
        var $span = $('span.hover', this).css('opacity', 0);
        $(this).hover(function () {
            $span.stop().fadeTo(500, 1);  
        }, function () {
    $span.stop().fadeTo(500, 0); 
        });
    });
});
```

But can we add sound to button in hover like flash buttons?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the **jQuery Sound Plugin** here: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js?rev=5750

Comment: Link is no longer valid.  Perhaps this is correct?
https://github.com/HansF/Fridgemagnet/blob/a6d572f3eb88f01616263b3053a6baad9dd7ed6b/js/jquery.sound.js